# Visual studio 2010 Express edition on Intel Atom N550 based netbook?

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010, netbook, intel-atom

The answer was yes for 1.6 Ghz Atom Processors...
For the N550, it's a 1.5 GHz DUAL CORE processor, will it be able to run VS 2010 ?

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/netfxsetup/thread/cc8816b6-0018-4b01-a555-966377110ac2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be fine. 100Mhz shouldn't matter a great deal.